# Dynamic arrayfield delete operation in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

As a Begineer in a react,i have just implementing a dynamic array field for learning but got a problem in delete operation of removing inputs fields from the row field with passing its id in deletefunction.How to overcome this problem?

**Code**

```
import React, { useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const initialValues = [
  {number: "",options: ""}
];
const Newrow = (props) => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");
  const [options, setoption] = useState([]);
  const addRow = () => {
    let _row = {
      number: "",
      options: ""
    };
    props.setData(_row);
  };
  const delrow = (i) => {
    data.splice(i,2)
    setData({})
  }
  return <div>
    <input
      type="number"
      value={number}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setNumber(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
  <input type="text"
   className="input"
   value={options}
   onChange={e=>{setoption(e.target.value)}}
   />
 <button
        type="submit"
     onClick={delrow}
        className="btn btn-danger">remove</button>
 </div>
};
export default function App(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const addRow = (row) => {
    setData([...data, row]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {[...data, ...initialValues].map((row, idx) => {
        return <Newrow setData={addRow} data={row} key={idx} delrow{idx} />;
      })}
      <button
        type="submit"
        onClick={() =>
          addRow({number: "",options: "" })}
        className="btn btn-success">Add</button> 
    </div>
  );
}
```